# Kali Linux Dual Boot - Wifi not working

Tags: wifi, bootcamp, unix, macos

I am struggling to find a detailed guide on how to troubleshoot wifi once Kali Linux 2.0 has been installed.

I dual booted on my MacBook Air (El Capitan) Kali Linux 2.0, and as I have been warned, and seemingly could not avoid, I can't find the wifi interface.

After reading Debian manual, and a bunch of others, and trying them out, I seem to run into problems that are not listed.

Primarily I've narrowed down to this site for the most concise help:

> https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Broadcom_BCM4311.2C_BCM4312.2C_BCM4313.2C_BCM4321.2C_BCM4322.2C_BCM43224.2C_BCM43225.2C_BCM43227.2C_BCM43228.2C_BCM43142.2C_BCM4331.2C_BCM4352.2C_BCM4360_devices_.28wl.29

[image: Module Wl not found]
Can't make Module wl to work, and not sure what else to do, I've done all other steps, don't know where to go form here.
My specs are:

- MacBook Air 15
- Installed Kali Linux 2.0  64 bit - Dual-Booted on an OS X Extended Journaled Partition
- My Wifi card chip is: BCM4360 14E4:43A0

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't know what do you mean by where to find `/etc/apt/sources.list` . It's in `/etc/apt/` as the path indicates. You can edit this from your terminal, I prefer using vim. `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`, hit Shift-G to jump to the end of the file, followed by 'o' to go into insert mode on a new line and write `deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free`. Then hit the escape key followed by  ':' then 'wq' and hit enter to save and quit. (you're free to use any editor you want just remember to run it as root with `sudo`)
2. Kali is based on Debian Wheezy: http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian
3. When the first step is done correctly you should be able to do what the debian wiki says.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm moving somewhere, the first 2 steps I pass, but on the 4th step, when I input command modprobe wl, I get FATAL

"root@KaliDark:~# modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma

root@KaliDark:~# modprobe wl

modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found."

Comment: can you make a screenshot or edit your post, I can't read clearly what's in the comment. Are you sure there wasn't a  typo error in `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms` ? did this command output a success ?

Comment: Hey so do you know what to do next? @maetsoh

Comment: Sorry can't help you I've looked around, I found many drivers but none for BCM4360